# Python Selenium ChromeDriver error. Message: element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to login in a URL. Getting element not interactable as error.

- The username textbox I can get it without any issue. I do it like:
  `driver.find_element_by_id("id_element").send_Keys("text", Keys.ENTER)`
- The password textbox I need to proceed with a different scope as I get the "element not interactable error"
  `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('password').value 'pass_text'")`

Finally when I want to submit the button to access I get again the "element not interactable error". I tried with the two scopes but either of them don't work.

1. `driver.find_element_by_id("btn_connect").click()`
2. `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('btn_connect').click()")`

HTML from the webpage

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group required">
        <label for="username">User name (or email) *</label>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autocomplete="username" readonly="">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button id="clearUsername" onclick="goToStep1()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">X</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="divPasswordId">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group required">
        <label for="password" id="labelPwd">Password *</label>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" onchange="onChangePwd(event)" onkeyup="onKeyUpPwd(event)">
        </div>
        <div id="errorMessagesPwd" class="error-messages" style="display: none">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row action action-no-border">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <ul>
            <li><a onclick="lostIdentifier(getSyUrl('sy-flow-production'))">I have lost my identifier</a></li>
            <li><a onclick="lostPassword(getSyUrl('sy-flow-production'))">I lost my password</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="btn_next" name="btn_newt" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right displayNone" onclick="checkIsSsoUser()">
            Next
        </button>
        <button id="btn_connect" name="btn_connection" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to fix this issue?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the URL or a sample HTML?  It's possible the button/password field is not interactable until certain conditions on the page are met.

Comment: @didac This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `ìd` to find an element, try using the `xpath`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("the_xpath_to_the_element")
```

In Chrome you can just use the developer tools to find your element and then right click on the element and click on copy xpath.